# Owin Implementation without Emai and Username field

Tags: asp.net-identity, owin

I am Using Identity 2.0.0 For Owin Implementation Using WebApi.

Problem::::
 when we implement Login Functionlity, Owin will Create ASpNetUser, other 3 tables.In Which Email and UserName Field are Require and Validated field.
But I don't want this fields as Require field, I have one token field, which is consider as a primary key field
so can I remoce this 2 field??

Comment: What do you want to do? You want to remove required validation?

Comment: yes i want to remove required validation and Email field syntax validation

Answer (score 0):

Go to Model folder in your project. Search for a UserName and Email property. Remove Reqired dataannotation attribute from property. And you are done.
If you don't find in Models folder, look in entire project or solution by Visual Studion's Find utility.

Let me know if you face any problem.